# Chrome does not show the page correctly (jQuery mobile css)

Tags: google-chrome, jquery-mobile, cross-browser

When I check below links with all major browsers like Firefox, Safari, Opera, IE, etc, I can easily see the page but the Chrome does not understand the jQuery CSS styles...
my Version is 26.0.1410.64 m   and I'm using Windows 7

https://www.weg2g.com/application/abovezest/trip-to-Costa-Rica-131230T81dc.html

Can https be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is your problem. If you look in the address bar on the right hand side there is a shield icon which says

> This page includes script from unauthenticated sources

When including the scripts in question try removing the protocol like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jquery.mobile.datebox.min.css" /> 
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jquery.mobile.datebox.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried your approach, but it does not work. It shows perfect under insecure mode...